# Why does adding console.log statements prevent test timeouts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, timeout, integration-testing, puppeteer

I've got some code that works fine running locally, tested using Supertest, but when the same test runs on CircleCI it fails due to time-outs.

The code in question is

```
for (const id of ids) {
  const urls = await scrapeLinks(id) // invokes puppeteer on a dockerised mock server
  await connectUrls(fbId, urls) // updates database using sequelize
}
```

Running locally this works fine.

Running the same tests on CircleCI this code takes too long to complete and the test times out.

**But** if I add a couple of `console.log` lines, then the tests do **not** time out

```
for (const id of ids) {
  console.log('start', id)
  const urls = await scrapeLinks(id) // invokes puppeteer on a dockerised mock server
  console.log('urls', urls)
  await connectUrls(fbId, urls) // updates database using sequelize
  console.log('end', id)
}
```

Running the tests on that works fine both locally, and on CircleCI.

My simple fix was of course simply to extend the timeout on my tests from 2 seconds to 5 seconds.

But my question is, why does the addition of `console.log` lines after each step make the code complete more quickly?

Comment: Which timeout exactly do you get? Is there a chance that CircleCI is throwing a timeout if there's no output for XXX time?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to CircleCI's [`no_output_timeout`](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#run) property, which is defined as:

> Elapsed time the command can run without output. The string is a decimal with unit suffix, such as “20m”, “1.25h”, “5s” (default: 10 minutes)

Therefore, if your program exceeds the given time set by this property without providing output, your program will timeout.